# Increase MediaPlayer volume beyond 100%

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, volume

Below code is working but not increasing the media player volume higher than the default max volume.Please help

```
AudioManager am = 
    (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setStreamVolume(
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
    0);
```

Answer (score 7):

The [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) class's [setVolume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setVolume(float,%20float)) method only accepts scalars in the range [0.0, 1.0], but the classes deriving from [AudioEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect) can be used to amplify the MediaPlayer's audio session.

For example, [LoudnessEnhancer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/LoudnessEnhancer) amplifies samples by a gain specified in millibels (i.e. hundredths of [decibels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel)):

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource("https://www.example.org/song.mp3");
player.prepare();

// Increase amplitude by 20%.
double audioPct = 1.2;
int gainmB = (int) Math.round(Math.log10(audioPct) * 2000);
LoudnessEnhancer enhancer = new LoudnessEnhancer(player.getAudioSessionId());
enhancer.setTargetGain(gainmB);
```

It's unclear from the documentation, but it appeared to me that LoudnessEnhancer doesn't work properly with negative gains, so you may still need to use MediaPlayer's setVolume() method if you want to decrease the volume.

[DynamicsProcessing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/DynamicsProcessing) provides multiple stages across multiple channels, including an input gain stage.

Answer (score 0):

For increasing the volume of the device beyond the system volume u have to go in engineers mode.for that save below code.and paste it in number entering box In calling option it will directly redirect you to the engineers mode

```
      *#*#3646633#*#*
```

By this you can access the system settings one thing make sure that don't use this without care it may affect your system performance.

Comment: Where u write this code what is your device model may be codes are different for different company so please Google and find the codec for engineers mode and try